# How do I access a variable from my main.py in my .kv file

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.label import Label


Balance = 0
Balance_string = str(Balance)

class MyWidget(Widget):
    def ads(self):
        global Balance
        Balance += 0.25
        Balance_string = str(Balance)
        print(Balance_string)
        return Balance_string

class BuzzMoneyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyWidget()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    BuzzMoneyApp().run()
```

** my .kv file **

```
<MyWidget>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: (0, 150,0)
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

    Button:
        center: self.parent.center
        font_size: 14
        height: 28
        background_color: (1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
        text: "Earn money"
        on_press:root.ads()
```

I want to access the Balance string variable from my main.py in my .kv file, so that I can display it on my screen.

Comment: Your `.kv` file seems to be incomplete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily reference `Properties` from your `python` inside your `kv`. Here is a modified version of your code that does that:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty, StringProperty
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

# Balance = 0
# Balance_string = str(Balance)

class MyWidget(Widget):
    Balance = NumericProperty(0)
    Balance_string = StringProperty('0')

    def ads(self):
        self.Balance += 0.25
        print(self.Balance_string)

    def on_Balance(self, *args):
        # update Balance_string whenever Balance changes
        self.Balance_string = str(self.Balance)

class BuzzMoneyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyWidget()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    BuzzMoneyApp().run()
```

And then you can reference those `Properties` in the `kv`:

```
<MyWidget>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: (0, 150,0)
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

    Button:
        center: self.parent.center
        font_size: 14
        height: 28
        background_color: (1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
        text: "Earn money"
        on_press:root.ads()
    Label:
        text: root.Balance_string  # root.Balance_string can be replaced with just str(root.Balance)
        size_hint: None, None
        size: self.texture_size
        pos: 300, 200
        color: 0,0,0,1
```

The `Properties` must be defined within an `EventDispatcher` (typically a `Widget`). The `on_Balance()` method is automatically triggered whenever the `Balance` `Property` changes, and it updates the `Balance_string` `Property`.
The `Balance_string` can be used within the `kv` as shown, and the `Label` will be updated whenever the `Balance_string` `Property` changes. Since the `Balance_string` is just the string value of `Balance`, it can be eliminated and replaced with `str(root.Balance)` in the `kv`.

Comment: I alderdy tried that i always get this error I can't post the error over here because it is 4 k chracters

Comment: here is the link to the error https://jpst.it/2Pi2W

Comment: That error says `AttributeError: 'MyWidget' object has no attribute 'Balance_string'`. Did you forget to add the line: `Balance_string = StringProperty('0')`?